Error 403 with Azure APIM while trying to execute an SQL Query with a where clause
We are building a RestAPI solution using Azure APIM and Azure function for external applications to query and retrieve data from Databricks Deltalake.
Only GET method is enabled on the endpoints
The solution expects either a tablename or an sql query as a parameter.
Now following requests work:
api_url = "https://dev.api.<XXXXXX>.com/external/<xxxxx>/v1/search?tablename=<catalog>.<schema>.<table_name>&query=ALL"

api_url = "https://dev.api.<XXXXXX>.com/external/<xxxxx>/v1/search?tablename=ALL&query=SELECT * FROM <catalog>.<schema>.<table_name>"

However these queries are erroring out:
api_url = "https://dev.api.<XXXXXX>.com/external/<xxxxx>/v1/search?tablename=ALL&query=SELECT * FROM <catalog>.<schema>.<table_name> WHERE <filter condition>"

api_url = "https://dev.api.<XXXXXX>.com/external/<xxxxx>/v1/search?tablename=ALL&query=SELECT * FROM <catalog>.<schema>.<table_name> LIMIT 100"

This is the error we get:


If the requests go via the Application Gateway, you can check its logs. Most likely you will see this is blocked by the Web Application Firewall rules.

@10p , I can check, but these requests works, so I highly doubt its gateway that blocks:
api_url = "https://dev.api..com/external//v1/search?tablename=ALL&query=SELECT * FROM ..<table_name>"
